# Call to a member function createQuery() on a non-object in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

but I have added `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repair\StoreBundle\Entity\registrationRepository")` in the registration entity, but I'm still getting an error near `createQuery()`;

my registrationRepository.php is

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * registrationRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */

class registrationRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    function __construct() {
    }

    public function auth($name,$password)
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

        $result = $em->createQuery("SELECT r.username,r.password FROM RepairStoreBundle:registration r where r.username='".$name."' and r.password='".$password."'")->getResult();
        return  $query;

    }   
}
```

My Controller is calling in this way

```php
$test = new registrationRepository();
$result = $test->auth($name);
```

Answer (score 4):

Creating `new registrationRepository`(instantiating) in Controller manualy is the wrong way of doing it. Instead you have to use doctrine `getRepository` method:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$registrationRepo = $em->getRepository('RepairStoreBundle:registration');
$result = $registrationRepo ->auth($name);
```

Read [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes).

### Update

Also you should remove `__construct` method from repository class.

Comment: Now i get what you mean, but OP issue isn't related to creation of a new Repo (even you're right; he have to call it and not to instatiate)

Comment: @DonCallisto, it is related. Because when he instantiates repository manualy dependence to doctrine is not injected. That's why `$this->getEntityManager()` returns null.

Comment: Thanks for the response i made the modifications which you said and changed in the function auth $em = $this->getEntityManager(); to $em = $this->getDoctrine->getEntityManager(); so it thrown me the error use findBy or findOneBy the actual problem i need to pass username,password by using this method how can i do that

Comment: @bangari, my answer is about changing the code in controller (not in auth function).

Comment: it is giving similar error cannot call to a memeberfunction createQuery() in the given answer what is $registrationRepo = $em->getRepository('RepairStoreBundle:Registration'); my bundle structure is Repair/StoreBundle/Entity/registration.php and registrationRepository.php thanks for being on conversation

Comment: @bangari, remove `__construct`